# Can't see icon on composite listview

Tags: android, listview, icons, composite

[image: screenshot]

I search a lot site, but it can't help me.
I have update every thing about android sdk manager.
But I can see in "Show Icon and Text" state.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Composite area and select Show icon and text,that way the list view and other will show up,hope this helps.!